# grouping array of Strings by their first value using java 8 Stream

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have a List of arrays containing two Strings:

```
List<String[]> pets = {["Alice", "dog"], ["Bob", "horse"], ["Alice", "cat"], ["Bob", "cat"]}
```

I want to turn them into a Map from String to List of Strings, like the following:

```
Map<String, List<String>>> pets = Map where
"Alice" maps to the List {"dog, "cat"}
"Bob" maps to the List {"horse", "cat"}
```

i.e. we take the first element of the array and group together all elements where the first elements are equal to each other. The imperative way of solving this would be to loop over the elements, and gradually building a Map. Is there any way to do this with java Streams, ie using a Collector or reduce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can!

You can group by the first element of each array which will be the map keys then apply the mapping collector to get the corresponding values.

```
 Map<String, List<String>> resultSet = pets.stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(array -> array[0],
                        collectingAndThen(mapping(e -> Arrays.copyOfRange(e, 1, e.length),
                                toList()),
                                f -> f.stream().flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                                .collect(toList()))));
```

or:

```
 Map<String, List<String>> resultSet = pets.stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(array -> array[0],
                flatMapping(e -> Arrays.stream(Arrays.copyOfRange(e, 1, e.length)),
                                    toList())));
```

Note, this solution uses the `flatMapping` collector which is only available as of JDK-9.

Comment: one could also use  `Arrays.stream(e).skip(1)`  instead of  `Arrays.stream(Arrays.copyOfRange(e, 1, e.length))` in the second example.

Comment: or even better, `Arrays.stream(e, 1, e.length)`

Comment: Thank you. Didn't see the groupingBy method Before.